# How do you pass a struct pointer through a function?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#define WIDTH_DATA 20

typedef struct
{
    float inhalt;
    unsigned int nr;
    int status;
} Paket;

typedef struct
{
    Paket Eingang[WIDTH_DATA];
    int laenge;
    float Ablage_A[WIDTH_DATA];
    float Ablage_B[WIDTH_DATA];
} Data_t;

#include <stdio.h>

int pruefe_status(int i1)
{

    if (i1==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

int vergleiche(unsigned int i1, unsigned int i2)
{

    if (i1<i2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int verteile_Pakete(Data_t *dv){

    int counterA=0,counterB=0;
    for (int i=0; i<WIDTH_DATA; i++)
    {
        if (pruefe_status(dv->Eingang[i].status)==0)
        {
            if(vergleiche(dv->Eingang[i].nr,5000))
            {
                dv->Ablage_A[counterA] = dv->Eingang[i].inhalt;
                counterA++;
            }
            else{
                dv->Ablage_B[counterB] = dv->Eingang[i].inhalt;
                counterB++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counterB + counterA;
}

int main(void)
{

    // Beispiel für testdv1:
    Data_t testdv1 = {{{12.5, 6067, 1}, {45.7, 3002, 0}, {56.0, 3456, 1}}, 3, {0}, {0}};
    Data_t testdv2 = {{{12.5, 6067, 0}, {45.7, 3002, 1}, {56.0, 3456, 1}}, 3, {0}, {0}};
    Data_t testdv3 = {{{12.5, 6067, 0}, {45.7, 7002, 0}, {56.0, 6456, 0}, {13.5, 6067, 0}, {1.7, 7772, 0}, {156.0, 5656, 0}}, 6, {0}, {0}};

    int Anzahl_pakete1=0;
    int Anzahl_pakete2=0;
    int Anzahl_pakete3=0;

    Anzahl_pakete1 = verteile_Pakete(&testdv1);
    Anzahl_pakete2 = verteile_Pakete(&testdv2);
    Anzahl_pakete3 = verteile_Pakete(&testdv3);

    printf("test 1:\nAnzahl bearbeitenden Pakete:%f\n",Anzahl_pakete1);



    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("AblageA %d: %f\nAblageB %d: %f\n",i,testdv1.Ablage_A[i],i,testdv1.Ablage_B[i]);
    }
    printf("test 2:\nAnzahl bearbeitenden Pakete:%f\n",Anzahl_pakete2);
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("AblageA %d: %f\nAblageB %d: %f\n",i,testdv2.Ablage_A[i],i,testdv2.Ablage_B[i]);
    }
    printf("test 3:\nAnzahl bearbeitenden Pakete:%f\n",Anzahl_pakete3);
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("AblageA %d: %f\nAblageB %d: %f\n",i,testdv3.Ablage_A[i],i,testdv3.Ablage_B[i]);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Why is the data in `testdv1` or `2` or `3` not going in the function `verteile_Pakete`?.

I tried to pass the address of these test variables to the function as a pointer but the values get lost and don't get through when I try to debug. So everything comes out as 0.

How can I solve this?

Comment: For starters: compile with all warnings enabled and fix your printfs; they are mostly wrong because you try to printf `int`s with the `%f` format specifier.

Comment: `Anzahl_pakete1` is `int` but format `%f` expects `double`.

Comment: "*So everything comes out as 0 this problem has plagued me and my friend for years help*", are you really stuck on this problem for **years**?

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings, that will save you *years* of scratching your head.

Comment: There are also warnings about `double` values being truncated to `float`. Please don't use `float` unless you have a very good reason why `double` can't be used. The `float` is a relic in old textbooks from the days when computers were emulating floating point, and `double` was a bit much for them. But `double` is the 'default' floating point type in C.

Comment: Helpful note: the addition of messages about how much you need HjÄÄÄLP and how long you have been stuck are good reasons to downvote. Please stick to technical writing if you can.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the compiler output (https://godbolt.org/z/jM43PY916) it warns you that you try to output the integer count as float.

Replace `%f` with `%d` in your format strings for integers and it works.